# Is it possible to rewrite this as a one liner?

Tags: c++

This is actual code.Here I am calling for_each to carry out the function shown in sum.Can this be reduced to writing the function inside the for_each statement itself?

```
int S;
struct sum
{
 sum(int& v): value(v){}
 void operator()(int data)const {value+=(int)((data+(data%S==0?0:S))/S)+2;}
 int& value;
};
int main()
{
  int cnt=0;
  S=5;
  for_each(flights.begin(),flights.end(),sum(cnt));
  cout<<cnt-2;
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: You can do this only in C++11 with lambda functions.

Comment: This is a perfectly valid question IMHO, although `flights` is never declared, initialized, nor defined.

Comment: Question should be re-opened.  It's a legitimate question.

Answer (score 9):

In C++11, you can, using lambdas with a capture:

```
int main()
{
  int cnt = 0;
  S = 5;
  for_each(
    flights.begin(), flights.end(),
    [&] (int data) {
        cnt += (data + (data % S == 0 ? 0 : S)) / S + 2;
    });
  cout << cnt - 2;
  return 0;
}
```

The way this reads is: you have an anonymous function taking an `int` argument, which captures (`[&]`) the surrounding context by reference. Note that this is *as efficient* as your solution since the compiler effectively creates the structure from the lambda for you.

– As Navaz noted int he comments, the cast is actually unnecessary. Furthermore, C-style casts are generally seen as deprecated – use C++ casts instead.

Comment: As an aside: How long between the update of a language and no longer having to put special qualifiers in answers that one is, indeed, referring to the language in its current version? ;-)

Comment: @DevSolar Well, In the case of C99, the qualification is only important when speaking of MSVC, in the case of C++11 the same applies until they properly implement the language.

Comment: @DevSolar Hard to say, I’m not even mentioning it all the time but since the question was specifically about the language feature it makes sense to mention it here. Otherwise I will sometimes tacitly assume a C++11 compiler.

Comment: `static_cast<int>` is not required!

Comment: Your solution is correct, but I would advise using `accumulate` instead of `for_each`, as it better describes the intent.

Answer (score 4):

You could use `std::accumulate` from `<numeric>` which perfectly expresses your intent to build  a sum.

```
int main()
{
    int flights[] = {1, 2, 3};
    int S = 5;
    std::cout << std::accumulate(
        begin(flights), end(flights), 0, 
        [S] (int sum, int data) { return sum + (int)((data+(data%S==0?0:S))/S)+2; })
        - 2;
}
```

Although you asked for a one liner, I prefer to give this non trivial lambda a name to increase readability.

```
int main()
{
    int flights[] = {1, 2, 3};
    auto theFooBarSum = [] (int sum, int data) 
        { return sum + (int)((data+(data%5==0?0:5))/5)+2; };
    int initialValue = 0;

    std::cout << std::accumulate(
        begin(flights), end(flights), initialValue , theFooBarSum) - 2;
}
```

Comment: You don't need to capture everything by reference, you should probably only capture `S` by value.

Comment: @user1444426 This uses lambdas from C++11. For pre C++11 compilers you could use boost lambda instead.